# SQL query combination of like and in?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
a. Select * from tableA where columnA like '%complete%';
b. Select * from tableA where columnA in ('complete','request');
```

The possible value for columnA is **complete, completed, request, requested..............**

My objective is to query those with value **complete, completed, request, requested**

Normally we will write query `where columnA in ('complete','completed','request','requested');`

Is there a way to write a much shorter query like `Select * from tableA where columnA in like (%complete%, %request%)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use multiple `OR`:

```
select * 
from tableA 
where columnA like '%complete%'
   or columnA like '%requested%'
   or ...
```

Use Join:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA t
JOIN VALUES (('%complete%'), ('%requested%'), ...) v(c)
  ON t.columnA LIKE v.c
```

Be aware that search pattern `%phrase%` is not SARG-able and query optimizer won't use index on that column, if exists any.

You should consider usage of [Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using CONTAINS like this:

```
select * from tableA
WHERE CONTAINS(columnA, '"complete*" OR "requested*" OR ...')
```

Comment: `CONTAINS`  can be applied only to  full-text indexed columns